# Changing radio button background on selected according to it value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**OBJECTIVE**

Trying to change the background color of a radio input that's been styled like a button so that when the user clicks on it, the color will change according to the radio value.

**EXPECTED RESULT**

When click button "NEUTRAL", change button background color to white.
When click button "GOOD", change button background color to green.
When click button "WATCHLIST", change button background to yellow.
When click button "UNDER MONOTORING", change button background to red.

**PROBLEM**

It doesn't change the background of the button accordingly, which is what I'm trying to do.

Appreciate some help here. Thank in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('label').click(function() {
    if ($("input:radio[name='category']:checked").val() == 'W') {
      $(this).addClass('whiteBG');
    }
    if ($("input:radio[name='category']:checked").val() == 'G') {
      $(this).addClass('greenBG');
    }
    if ($("input:radio[name='category']:checked").val() == 'Y') {
      $(this).addClass('yellowBG');
    }
    if ($("input:radio[name='category']:checked").val() == 'R') {
      $(this).addClass('redBG');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input[type=radio],
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: block;
  appearance: button;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  -ms-appearance: button;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #DDDDDD;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #111111;
  border: 2px solid #AAAAAA;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

.whiteBG {
  background-color: #FFF000;
}

.greenBG {
  background-color: #0F0000;
}

.yellowBG {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.redBG {
  background-color: #F00000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>PERSON CATEGORY SELECTION</legend>
    <label for="neutral">
              <input type="radio" class="button" id="neutral" name="category" value="W" >NEUTRAL</input>
          </label>
    <label for="good">
              <input type="radio" class="button" id="good" name="category" value="G">GOOD</input>
          </label>
    <label for="watchlist">
              <input type="radio" class="button" id="watchlist" name="category" value="Y">WATCHLIST</input>
          </label>
    <label for="monitor">
              <input type="radio" class="button" id="monitor " name="category" value="R">UNDER MONOTORING</input>
          </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you saying that clicking one of the buttons should change *that* button's background colour to the specified colour and change the other buttons back to grey?

Comment: Yes, the others should change back to grey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems in your code:

- The `#` colour codes that you had in your CSS didn't reflect the colours you were trying to assign. These hex codes need to be either abbreviated three-digit RGB values or six-digit RGB values with two digits per colour, i.e., either `#RGB` or `#RRGGBB`, but it was like you mixed the two options by adding "000" to the end of what would otherwise be the right three-digit hex codes for the colours you wanted. Either remove the trailing `000` from each one, or change to the correct six-digit hex codes.
- You didn't have any code to remove the class from a button when the other buttons are clicked.

Your JS code seems overly complicated. I would bind the click handler to the radio buttons themselves, because then `this.value` will give you the value of the button just clicked, thus simplifying your `if` conditions a lot. You can use `$(this).parent()` to then get to the label element to style it.

I've introduced a variable called `buttons` that is the jQuery object containing all of the buttons, because then inside the handler you can say `buttons.not(this).parent()` to get a jQuery object containing all of the other buttons' parent label elements and remove the colour class from them to make them grey again.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var buttons = $("input:radio[name='category']").click(function() {
    buttons.not(this).parent().removeClass('whiteBG greenBG yellowBG redBG');
    var label = $(this).parent();
    if (this.value == 'W') {
      label.addClass('whiteBG');
    } else if (this.value == 'G') {
      label.addClass('greenBG');
    } else if (this.value == 'Y') {
      label.addClass('yellowBG');
    } else if (this.value == 'R') {
      label.addClass('redBG');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] { display: none; }

label {
  display: block;
  appearance: button; -webkit-appearance: button; -moz-appearance: button; -ms-appearance: button;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight: 400;
  background: #DDDDDD;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #111111;
  border: 2px solid #AAAAAA;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

.whiteBG { background-color: #FFF; }

.greenBG { background-color: #0F0; }

.yellowBG { background-color: #FF0; }

.redBG { background-color: #F00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>PERSON CATEGORY SELECTION</legend>
    <label for="neutral">
        <input type="radio" class="button" id="neutral" name="category" value="W" >NEUTRAL</input>
    </label>
    <label for="good">
         <input type="radio" class="button" id="good" name="category" value="G">GOOD</input>
    </label>
    <label for="watchlist">
         <input type="radio" class="button" id="watchlist" name="category" value="Y">WATCHLIST</input>
    </label>
    <label for="monitor">
         <input type="radio" class="button" id="monitor" name="category" value="R">UNDER MONOTORING</input>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: If I have a category value read from db let say "R", how to set the button check or selected on page load?

Comment: You could trigger the click event on that particular button by using its value attribute in the selector: assuming the required "R" value is in a variable `savedVal` then something like `$("input:radio[name='category'][value='" + savedVal + "']").click()` (added inside your existing document ready handier after the other code).

Comment: What I mean that I have a passing value "R" from other page and I want make "UNDER MONITORING" button to be selected and background set to red color as a default value.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. So first get the value from the request parameters (if you can't figure out how to do that ask another question specifically about that, mentioning which server-side technology you're using), and once you have the value in a variable try like I showed in the previous comment.

Comment: Ok I add as below:

Comment: Ok I added var savedVal = '<%=Request.QueryString("cat")%>';  where cat=R after document.ready and added $("input:radio[name='category'][value='" + savedVal + "']").click() after the other code at the end of before closing the document.ready. Nothing happen, expected "UNDER MONITORING" has been selected and turn red as a default.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your `background-color` show up, you should set `appearance` properties on `label` to `none` instead of `button`.

```
label {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
}
```

You should remove all CSS classes from your `button` on click before you set the new CSS class.

Comment: *"In order to make your background-color show up"* - In the OP's snippet different background colours are already showing up on click, just not the expected colours. Changing `appearance` to `none` doesn't help with the colours, and also the OP obviously wants the labels to look like buttons. I'm not sure why you tried to edit that change into *my* answer when the code I've shown works as is.

Comment: @nnnnnn I don't know which browser you are using, but the color is not showing up in Chrome in both OP's and your snippet. That's why I edited your answer. I thought wasn't able to see the color was a big problem as well.

Comment: I only tested in Chrome. Worked fine for me.

Comment: Weird, the snippet in OP doesn't work for me in Mac Chrome 60.0.3112.101.